# How to query Redis Cache AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

We have a redis cluster configured on AWS. 
What are the steps to access key value pairs on this cluster?

PS: I know how to check redis key/values on local machine using redis-cli. The steps I take to do that are :

1. use cmd or powershell to cd to where redis-cli.exe resides
2. run redis-cli.exe
3. type commands like KEY *

Comment: You simply connect to the redis host using the `-H` parameter, via `redis-cli`.  You'll also need to make sure you have the appropriate security group ingress rules defined.

Comment: Where do I install redis-cli? on my local machine?@LukePeterson would you please be able to explain the steps or any guide I can follow?

Comment: Anywhere that has network access to your Elasticache cluster will work.